# T-SQL Case statement utilizing substring and isnumeric

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, substring, isnumeric

I have a T-SQL stored proc that supplies a good amount of data to a grid on a .NET page....so much so that I put choices at the top of the page for "0-9" and each letter in the alphabet so that when the user clicks the letter I want to filter my results based on results that begin with that first letter.  Let's say we're using product names.  So if the user clicks on "A" I only want my stored proc to return results where SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, 1) = "A".

Where I'm getting hung up is on product names that begin with a number.  In that case I want to fetch all ProductName values where ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, 1)) = 1.  I'm using an input parameter called @FL.  @FL will either be a zero (we have few products that begin with numerics, so I lump them all together this way).

Of course there's also the alternative of WHERE SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2'.....) but even then, I've never been able to devise a CASE statement that will do an = on one evaluation and an IN statement for the other.

Here's what I have in my proc for the CASE part of my WHERE clause.  It doesn't work, but it may be valuable if only from a pseudocode standpoint.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have.

```
AND CASE @FL
    WHEN "0" THEN
    CASE WHEN @FL = "0" THEN
        isnumeric(substring(dbo.AssnCtrl.Name, 1, 1)) = 1
    ELSE
        SUBSTRING(dbo.AssnCtrl.Name, 1, 1) = @FL            
    END
END
```

*** I know that this use of the CASE statement is "non-standard", but I found it online and thought it had some promise.  But attempts to use a single CASE statement yielded the same result (an error near '=').

Comment: The inner CASE is redundant - the ISNUMBERIC will always be executed because @FL was already tested for being "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use Like operator ?

```
   Where dbo.AssnCtrl.Name Like @FL + '%'
```

When they select the Any Number option, pass in @FL as  '[0-9]'

(I assume you have an index on this name column ?)

Comment: Like your thinking, but given that @FL will be 0 or a letter, how would that work for values where the first character is 1-9?  I don't see how that works for numerics.

Comment: @Charles - because there are so few numeric results, I've combined 0-9 in my page link and an @FL value of 0 is represented for *any* product that begins with a numeric character....make sense?

Comment: A-ha!  Now I see your point!  I wasn't aware of the range possiblities of LIKE.  So I can say AND substring(assnctrl.name, 1, 1) LIKE CASE when @FL = '0' then '[0-9]' else @FL.

Comment: Or you can change your stored procedure to edit the incoming paramenter:  if @FL='0' Set @FL='[0-9]'. This lets you get rid of the slow CASE statement.

Comment: @Mike, you don't even need the `Substring()`, that's the point of the wildcard. It will match anything that starts with @FL Use `Where assnctrl.name Like @FL + '%'`

Answer (score 1):

To steal a bit from Charles:

```
AND Substring(dbo.AssnCtrl.Name, 1, 1) Like
  CASE WHEN @FL = '0' THEN '[0-9]'
    ELSE @FL            
  END
```

Comment: Doh. Comments in Charles answer updated to include my solution.

Comment: better still is to eliminate the call to substring function. `AND dbo.AssnCtrl.Name Like CASE @FL WHEN '0' THEN '[0-9]' ELSE @FL END + '%' `

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
AND (
        isnumeric(substring(dbo.AssnCtrl.Name, 1, 1)) = 1
    or
        SUBSTRING(dbo.AssnCtrl.Name, 1, 1) = @FL    )
```

this works for me:

```
select * from casefile where
isnumeric(substring(pmin,1,1)) = 1
or 
substring(pmin,1,1) = 'a'
```